# large scale rpc server built on http

Tags: java, http, rpc

i am building a rpc server using http that serves 100000 clients. the server is using tomcat as container, basiclly each request made by client will be very fast because server will start a new thread to handle the request so there is no long-hold request waiting return value.

i am wondering what tuning ponits are for this senario? the frist thing i know is ipv4.contrack which controls max tcp connctions as well as some other parameters about tcp connection recycle.

besides, what else should i look into? tomcat threadpool maybe a one. though i think 100000 clicents will unlikely make request concurrently, i do want to make the sever be able to serve concurrently requests as many as possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have to define your requirements. Something like:

- max-concurrent-connections
- max-request-processing-time
- etc

After that I would suggest to do extensive load testing. Create basic (but close to real life) implementation of your server and start testing.

Initially you can use *ab* tool and later switch to JMeter, for example.

ab will generated something like the following:

```
 ab -c 10 -n 100 http://www.xyz.com/
This is ApacheBench, Version 1.3d <$Revision: 1.73 $> apache-1.3
Copyright (c) 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Copyright (c) 2006 The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking www.xyz.com (be patient).....done
Server Software: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Server Hostname: www.xyz.de
Server Port: 80

Document Path: /
Document Length: 3112 bytes

Concurrency Level: 10
Time taken for tests: 0.659 seconds
Complete requests: 100
Failed requests: 0
Broken pipe errors: 0
Total transferred: 367003 bytes
HTML transferred: 339208 bytes
Requests per second: 151.75 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request: 65.90 [ms] (mean)
Time per request: 6.59 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate: 556.91 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connnection Times (ms)
min mean[+/-sd] median max
Connect: 0 0 0.5 0 6
Processing: 8 63 144.6 12 514
Waiting: 8 63 144.7 12 513
Total: 8 64 144.8 12 514

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
50% 12
66% 15
75% 19
80% 19
90% 491
95% 491
98% 512
99% 514
100% 514 (last request)
```

It might be helpful to create a plot:

[image]

Having that you can proceed with all performance optimizations and tweaking, because it will be possible to see results immediately.

It is likely you'll need to tune your application first, but after that you have quite a lot of options, including the following:

- JVM tuning (GC tuning, etc)
- Connectors tuning
- Compression
- NIO
- HTTP 1.1 specific stuff
- and so on

Just use correct approach and start doing something -- it will require some time.

**EDIT** Tomcat tuning tips

Frankly speaking there are so much different articles on this topic:

- [Chapter 4. Tomcat Performance Tuning](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/0596003188/tomcat-performance-tuning/tomcat-chp-4)
- [OPTIMISING AND TUNING APACHE TOMCAT](http://blog.springsource.org/2008/10/14/optimising-and-tuning-apache-tomcat-part-2/)
- [Tomcat 6 performance tuning](http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/java_app/tomcat6/tomcat6_tuning.htm)
- [Tomcat configuration $Tomcat/conf/server.xml](http://javamaster.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/apache-tomcat-tuning-guide/)

There is no 100% universal solution, you should do deep investigation yourself

Comment: Thanks Renat. Actually I have looked in ab before. Do you have detailed tuning points practice? the problem is even if I got the benchmark, I still don't know where to start tuning

Comment: You are welcome, see updated. I would suggest to start producing benchmark results every time you create a build.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing to understand is how your system will be used and what the dominant performance factor (or factors) will be. In other words, are you going to be I/O bound or CPU bound? Once you understand that, you can start to design performance tests that give you a baseline measurement of your system's performance under a realistic testing scenario and then vary your system configuration (e.g, the size of the thread-pool or heap) to see what effect that has on the system performance.

I'd also recommend reading [this](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/usenix99/full_papers/pai/pai.pdf) paper. Even though it's more than ten years old now, the design discussion and tradeoffs are still applicable today. At a minimum, it should help you to think about what performance-tuning aspects will be most important to your system.